# Sending bulk email using cronjob in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cron, cakephp-2.3, swiftmailer

I am developing a website which has a newsletter module. I want to send newsletters to the 3000+ users on specific time. Right now i am using the CakePHP mailer which is showing error on maximum_execution time. I have increased the maximum execution time but still it is not working.

I googled it and everyone recomending me to use SwiftMailer, but i didn't getting a proper tutorial on this.

Please help me so i can send bulk emails using cron job.

Comment: set max execution time on the top ini_set('max_execution_time', -1);

Comment: any efforts made so far? http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/CraZyLeGs/2006/12/18/swiftmailer-component-tutorial visit this link

Comment: I would send them in batches. So within your cron method, look up first 50 (or whatever amount) unsent mails that are now due to be sent - ordered by oldest first. Then process those and kick the sent ones off the list (by a status change or something similar)